# Checking multiple condition with numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe with several lines and columns and I have transformed it into a numpy array to speed-up the calculations.
The first five columns of the Dataframe looked like this:

```
par1      par2      par3      par4      par5
1.502366  2.425301  0.990374  1.404174  1.929536
1.330468  1.460574  0.917349  1.172675  0.766603 
1.212440  1.457865  0.947623  1.235930  0.890041 
1.222362  1.348485  0.963692  1.241781  0.892205 
...
```

These columns are now stored in a numpy array `a = df.values`

I need to check whether *at least two* of the five columns satisfy a condition (i.e., their value is larger than a certain threshold). Initially I wrote a function that performed the operation directly on the dataframe. However, because I have a very large amount of data and need to repeat the calculations over and over, I switched to numpy to take advantage of the vectorization.

To check the condition I was thinking to use

```
df['Result'] = np.where(condition_on_parameters > 2, True, False)
```

However, I cannot figure out how to write the `condition_on_parameters` such that it returns a True of False when at least 2 out of the 5 parameters are larger than the threshold. I thought to use the `sum()` function on the `condition_on_parameters` but I am not sure how to write such condition.

**EDIT**
It is important to specify that the thresholds are different for each parameter. For example `thr1=1.2, thr2=2.0, thr3=1.5, thr4=2.2, thr5=3.0`. So I need to check that par1 > thr1, par2 > thr2, ..., par5 > thr5.

Comment: It's `df.values` without `()`. Converting to `numpy` won't speed up computation, a `dataframe` is already a `np.array` under the hood. `df.gt(.5).sum(1).ge(2)` does what you want for the threshold `.5`.

Comment: wow! came here to answer, and yet I'm learning new stuff...the magic of SO <3 Thanks @MichaelSzczesny for sharing this! :D

Comment: This is nice, but can it work with multiple conditions? For example par1 > 0.5, par2 > 1.2, par3 > 3, etc. In this case I would need to specify the condition on each column, then sum and check when it is greater or equal to 2.

Comment: @user12394113 - Please update your question if you have additional requirements. It would help if you provide a minimal input example with example conditions and expected output. You can exploit broadcasting `df.gt([.5,.3,.2,.5,.8]).sum(1).ge(2)`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: Genius!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `condition_on_parameters` returns an array the sames size as `a` with entries as `True` or `False`, you can use `np.sum(condition_on_parameters, axis=1)` to sum over the true values (`True` has a numerical values of 1) of each row. This provides a 1D array with entries as the number of columns that meet the condition. This array can then be used with `where` to get the row numbers you are looking for.

```
df['result'] = np.where(np.sum(condition_on_parameters, axis=1) > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [numpy.any](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html)

```py
a = np.array(\
[[1.502366,  2.425301,  0.990374,  1.404174,  1.929536],
[1.330468,  1.460574,  0.917349,  1.172675,  0.766603 ],
[1.212440,  1.457865,  0.947623,  1.235930,  0.890041 ],
[1.222362,  1.348485,  0.963692,  1.241781,  0.892205 ]]);
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=[f'par{i}' for i in range(1, 6)])
df['Result'] = np.any(df > 1.46, axis=1) # append the result column
```

Gives the following dataframe

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Can you exploit pandas functionalities? For example, you can efficiently check conditions on multiple rows/columns with `.apply` and then `.sum(axis=1)`.

Here some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.50, 2.42, 0.88], [0.98,1.3, 0.56]], columns=['par1', 'par2', 'par3'])

# custom_condition, e.g. value less or equal than threshold
def leq(x, t):
     return x<=t

condition = df.apply(lambda x: leq(x, 1)).sum(axis=1)
# filter
df.loc[condition >=2]
```

I think this should be equivalent to numpy in terms of efficiency as pandas is ultimately build on top of that, however I'm not entirely sure...